# How to kill explorer.exe when it's frozen on the start screen?

Tags: windows-10, windows-8.1, windows-explorer, freeze

I'm trying to get Windows 8.1 explorer.exe to run on Windows 10 (like Ex7ForW8).

My explorer.exe was running in IDA and I opened the start screen. I then pressed the down arrow for "more apps". At that point IDA hit a breakpoint and the screen froze halfway through the animation.

Ctrl+Alt+Delete works but the task manager seems to open in the background, behind the start screen (normally the start screen goes away when it's opened)... I'm also able to Switch User (but I have no other user), Lock, Change password, Open Magnifier and an On-screen keyboard.

Is there any way I could kill explorer.exe if it's frozen on the start screen? I haven't saved for a long time would lose hours of work if I had to restart.

Comment: use a 2nd monitor and open taskmgr/process explorer/process hacker here before trying to debug. Also try [OldNewExplorer](http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/170375-oldnewexplorer-118/) to bring old features back to Explorer

Comment: @magicandre1981: Wow, that worked! The second monitor wasn't frozen on start so I could open Task Manager. Thank you so much :)

Comment: ok, I've posted it as answer, so that you can [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try to use a 2nd monitor and open taskmgr/[process explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx)/[process hacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/downloads.php) here before trying to debug the application on the main monitor.

You should also try [OldNewExplorer](http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/170375-oldnewexplorer-118/) to bring old features back to Explorer :

> OldNewExplorer is the Windows 10 (and Windows 8.1, and 8) shell
>   extension / tweaker which can undo "improvements" to file browsing
>   made in newer Windows version. Everything is optional for your liking.

[image]